# racket/scheme web monitoring program crash always

Tags: crash, web, scheme, monitoring, racket

I made the following web monitoring program, but it always crashes.
I wonder what's going wrong.
there is no error. 
the program just freezes when I click the button. 
I am on windows xp sp3. 
I run the program from DrRacket 5.2.1

```
#lang racket/gui
(require net/url)
(require racket/date)

(define (path->txt-list path)
  (when (not (equal? path #f))
  (define port (open-input-file path))
  (define txt-list '())
  (define (loop [line (read-line port 'return-linefeed)])
    (when (not (eof-object? line))
      (set! txt-list (list txt-list line)) (loop)))
  (loop) 
  (flatten txt-list)))

(define (find-word src-url-str word)
  (define src-url (string->url src-url-str))
  (define word-len (string-length word))
  (define found 0)
  (define in (get-pure-port src-url))
  (define response-str (port->string in))
  (define src-len (string-length response-str))

  (do 
      ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
    ((or 
      (= i (- src-len 1)) 
      (< (- src-len 1) (+ i word-len))) 
     found)
      (set! in (get-pure-port src-url))
      (set! response-str (port->string in))
      (close-input-port in)
      (set! src-len (string-length response-str))
      (if (string=? (substring response-str i (+ i word-len)) word) 
          (set! found (+ found 1)) 
          0))
  found)


(define (find-all src-url-str txt-file-path)
  (when (not (equal? txt-file-path #f))
  (define find-list (path->txt-list txt-file-path))
  (define number-of-founds 0)
  (for-each (lambda 
                (word) 
              (set! number-of-founds (+ number-of-founds (find-word src-url-str word)))) 
            find-list)
  number-of-founds))


(define (cb-start-btn)
  (define target-url-str (send txt-in get-value))
  (define target-file-path (get-file))
  (define now (current-date))
  (define number-of-founds (find-all target-url-str target-file-path))
  (when (real? number-of-founds)
    (when (> number-of-founds 0)
      (begin (send msg set-label
                   (format "number of founds:~a ~a" 
                           number-of-founds
                           (format "(hour:~a minute:~a second:~a)" 
                                   (date-hour now) 
                                   (date-minute now) 
                                   (date-second now))))
             (play-sound "C:/WINDOWS/Media/ringin.wav"))))
  (cb-start-btn))



(define f (new frame% (label "Luragi Monitor")))
(define txt-in (new text-field% (label "URL for monitoring") (parent f)))
(define msg (new message% (label "") (parent f)))
(define button (new button% (label "paste URL and click here to select txt file(words splitted with return) and go") (parent f) (callback (lambda (b e) (cb-start-btn)))))
(send f show #t)
```

Comment: What error message do you get?  What kind of system are you on?  How did you run the program?

Providing more detail makes it easier for people to answer your questions.

Comment: oh thanks for your replying. there is no error. the program just freezes when I click the button. I am on windows xp sp3. I run the program from DrRacket 5.2.1

Comment: have you tried debugging? DrRacket has a great IDE/debugger...that's the best way to narrow down the issue.

Comment: thank you. I debug it but I have no luck so far.. T.T

Comment: I tried running your code in my DrRacket and it pops up a GUI. Maybe you can try running your code in a [nightly build](http://pre.racket-lang.org/installers/). It's possible there was a bug that was fixed.